# Text justification equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know the equation for letter justification. I am racking my brains trying to figure it out so if anyone can help that would be great. I am trying to justify the individual letters in a string, not whole words.

I am working in pixels and am already able to calculate the following:

- The width (in pixels) that the string takes up
- The width (in pixels) of the container that the string will populate
- The width (in pixels) of each individual character

I need to know how to calculate the spacing between each character of a string to fill a container. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: (length of container - sum of lengths of characters) divided by (one less than the number of characters). Assuming no ending and beginning spacing, otherwise subtract these from the numerator as well.

Comment: Your comment helped a lot! Thank you. There is no beginning spacing but I would like the last letter to sit as close to the end as possible. What is the numerator? Sorry I am so bad at maths!

Comment: Numerator =(length of container- sum of lengths of characters - spacing at beginning -spacing at end). Denominator=(number of characters -1).  fixed Inner-character spacing= Numerator/denominator.

Comment: Great thanks! I have it working, however I have had to increase the size of the variable for the container by an amount.

Comment: After the third letter and subsequent letters, extra space seems to be getting added.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934937/justifing-letters-html5-canvas

Comment: can you post the out put of that program

Comment: Hi, yes: http://jsfiddle.net/beingalex1981/mWw3F/5/

Comment: It's actually more difficult than I thought as each letter has a different width in pixels. For example: `i` is not as wide as `W'

Comment: your answer helped me a lot! The final solution, using your help was found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934937/justifing-letters-html5-canvas-js-fiddle-example